# Having trouble getting acts_as_audited installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, acts-as-audited

I'm trying to install **acts_as_audited** on rails 3, but the docs seem to only refer to pre rails 3 style installs, anyone got any tips?

Heres the details,
https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited

I have the gem installed, it shows up when I type
**gem list**

however the generator does not appear to be available when I try

**rails generate audited_migration add_audits_table**

If anyone has a preferred audit trail idea, feel free to shout.

---

**Part B!**

So now I have the right branch, I tried to install it as per the new instructions.
But I get the following error **Could not find gem 'acts_as_audited (= 2.0.0.rc1, runtime)' in any of the gem sources.**

I've added the following to my gemfile, (source was a later addition as I tried to get it working)
**source 'http://gems.github.com'**
**gem 'acts_as_audited', '2.0.0.rc1'**

typing *gem env* in terminal gives,

```
gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.4.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/tmulcahy/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/", "http://gems.github.com/"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
     - http://gems.github.com/
```

Can you help any further?
This may be stupid but these days my biggest problem with rails is getting gems installed, I always seem to have these kind of problems. It would be nice to knock it on the head once and for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the rails3 branch? https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited/tree/rails3

Update:

Scratch that, try using this gem instead. https://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_audited_rails3. Set the Gemfile source back to `source :rubygems` as well.

Comment: Will give that a try, was not aware there was a rails 3 branch.

Comment: Have added a part B to the question as I am still having problems. Would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I updated my answer with a rails3 version of the gem hosted at rubygems.org

Comment: Thanks Beerlington, will try that this evening.

Answer (score 0):

I am using acts_as_audited 2.0.0.rc7 with Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.9 with no issues.

In my Gemfile I put this:

```
gem "acts_as_audited",  "2.0.0.rc7"
```

Then I just ran 'bundle install' from my rails root, no problems. After that I just followed the normal installation steps on the acts_as_audited github:

```
$ rails g acts_as_audited:install

$ rake db:migrate
```

This also works in Ruby 1.8.7 environment.